# windows.jQuery versus jQuery as a parameter

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to protect my jquery code from global scope and I decided to use encapsulation. However, I see some developers put window.jQuery and some just jQuery as a parameter. What's the difference between the two?

```
(function ($) {

}(window.jQuery));

//versus

(function ($) {

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: No difference, `jQuery` is defined in global scope.

Comment: The jQuery source code actually contains this line, right at the end: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`